# Unable to build docker image with Jenkinsfile

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

From this https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/ I'd like to pass a specific path of dockerfile.

directory structure under `$jenkins_home/workspace/<project>`

```
├── dockerfiles
    ├── hello
    │   └── Dockerfile
├── Jenkinsfile
```

the contents in jenkinsfile looks like this

```
stage('Build Image') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def dockerfile = "Dockerfile.${env.branchName}"
                    def dockerImage = docker.build("${imageName}" + ":" + "${imageTag}", "-f ${dockerfile} ./dockerfiles")
                }
            }
        }
```

resulting in this error

```
+ docker build -t localhost:32000/hello:feature -f Dockerfile.hello ./dockerfiles
unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /var/jenkins_home/workspace/simple_project/Dockerfile.hello: no such file or directory
```

Comment: Like the error message says, it doesn't like symlinks, specifically symlinks to anything outside the current directory for security reasons.

Comment: @BTH.S3 Does the solution i provided works for you

Answer (score 0):

It looks that `Dockerfile.hello` is not in the specific path as mentioned.

```
docker build -t localhost:32000/hello:feature -f Dockerfile.hello ./dockerfiles
```

If your Dockerfile is in another directory /folder then you need to specify the directory explicitly:

So if you have a `Dockerfile` present in `"/dockerfiles/hello"` directory you would pass from Jenkinsfile as:

```
 def dockerImage= docker.build("${imageName}" + ":" + "${imageTag}", "./dockerfiles/hello")
```

Builds image from the Dockerfile found at ./dockerfiles/hello/Dockerfile.